# I am upgraded my old flutter to latest version , how can solve this errors?

Tags: flutter, firebase

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

I am flutter upgraded after I am facing this problems how can help me

Answer (score 0):

Check for Flutter and Plugin Updates:

Make sure you are using the latest version of Flutter and your plugins. Run **flutter doctor** and ensure that your Flutter environment is up to date. You might need to update Flutter or certain packages.
Clean and Rebuild Your Project:

Sometimes, issues can be resolved by cleaning the project and rebuilding it. You can do this by running:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
flutter run
```

Dependencies to be added in Project Level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    ...
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.